# how to connect nodejs application to google cloud mysql (no bs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I've seen a ton of conflicting answers and I want this thread to be very conclusive. I'm running a Node.js app that needs to have a server endpoint to call a google mysql database.

The SQL call I'm making in `server.js` should be fine, empty though. Regardless, the break point isn't at the SQL call.

There's no enforced password set up so I have those credentials set up as

```
...
user: 'root',
password: '',
...
```

and I'm currently not using the `socketPort` configuration option.

[image]

Respond if you need any more information about the database.

This is a full stack trace, you can see it yourself by running `npm run dev`

```
Error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUTat Connection._handleConnectTimeout (C:\Users\********\Projects\security-project\security-dashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:412:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\********\Projects\security-project\security-dashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\********\Projects\security-project\security-dashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\*******\Projects\security-project\security-dashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*********\Projects\security-project\security-dashboard\database.js:26:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
[ ready ] compiled successfully
```

Comment: For yourself, or anyone that clones your repo to try and make it work, connecting to that DB will be blocked unless the IP address is whitelisted. Have you already taken the appropriate steps to make sure that the IP address of the machine where your NodeJS code is running is allowed to connect to the Google Cloud MySQL database? - [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP)

Comment: No I have not, but wouldn’t that just be a stopgap for local development? The goal is to get this fully deployed on GAE @joshuat

Comment: It matters based on your current code in `database.js`, which relies on connecting to the DB via public IP instead of by path, and the connection getting blocked or the lookup by IP failing could be one explanation for the `ETIMEDOUT` error you are getting. But, if you are going to be running the code in the same environment (GAE), you should be using [this code](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#connecting_to_cloud_sql) anyways, and specifying `socketPath` instead of `host` in your `mysql.createConnection` call.